# Diagram data series is not formatted correctly

Tags: excel, vba, charts, excel-charts

I have the following situation:
I have a chart based on a pivot table (pivot chart).
If certain conditions exist, my existing macro changes the background color of a data series from "Automatic" to "Pattern Fill" (dotted background). This works fine, the macro looks like this:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(31).Select

With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Patterned msoPattern10Percent
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .BackColor.RGB = RGB(135, 206, 235)

End With
```

However, if the conditions change, the background color should be set back to "Automatic" using a macro.
I tried to record this using macro recording and the result looks like this:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Diagramm 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(31).Select

Selection.Format.Fill
.Visible = msoTrue
```

The problem now is that nothing is changed after execution - so the background remains dotted.
Does anyone know how to set the background color back to "Automatic" using a macro? Possibly using a .Patterned attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you were recording there was no setting under `Pattern Fill` for Automatic, or even for None.

To switch from a pattern to the equivalent of Automatic you need to set a few settings; in particular, `.Solid` turns off the patterning.

```
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With
```

You would set the `ForeColor` to what you consider to be *automatic*. (You can also set some BackColor perhaps depending on the chart type, and whether you want a gradient.)

I suppose another approach is to use the same Fore and BackColor to achieve a solid pattern.

---

When looking at the fill options there is an `Automatic` option to click, but you still have to choose a colour; it generates code equivalent to that above (unless you choose a theme colour).

---

From this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097105/vba-chart-series-set-color-fill-to-automatic) you can use the deprecated, but still working, Excel 2003 syntax to apply `xlAutomatic`:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
```

(Personally, I would rather specify the 'defaults' or theme colours explicitly.)

Comment: This doesn't really work for me because I would have to assign each Chart-Object to a color individually (I do sometimes have more than 40 Chart-Objects)

Comment: @Andreas That is a completely separate, and new, question. The same answer applies but you could use a loop to apply the same code to a collection of chart objects.

Comment: If I manually change the background-color back to "automatic", I do not have to select any colors as Excel automatically sets the colors back to the original color (before I executed the first macro). This is exactly the behaviour I would like to generate with the new macro

Comment: perfect - Interior.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic is what I was looking for, thank you very much!